# Part Number for Motherboard ATX 24 Pin Male Header

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, atx, molex

The 24 pin ATX connector (male, housing) on my motherboard has been melted to the 24 pin connector from the PSU.

I will be replacing the motherboard's 24 pin ATX connector myself, but am not able to find the part number to purchase a replacement. I purchased [`WM17809-ND` from Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0438790032/WM17809-ND/1643352) but it turns out to be the wrong part.

What's its part number and where can I find a black colored replacement?

Answer (score 1):

[This is what you are looking for.](http://www.moddiy.com/products/24%252dPin-ATX-Power-Male-Header-Connector-%252d-Straight-%252d-Black.html?gclid=CjgKEAjw2KCcBRCQ_6mztcunhEgSJABPxOF1rdquTZM3gEkgvz48boQ8UK86vGIwakXQZdNumkFtbfD_BwE) It's also available in a [90 degree layout](http://www.moddiy.com/products/24%252dPin-ATX-Power-Male-Header-Connector-%252d-90%25-Angled-%252d-Black.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the 39-29-9246. There are lots of copies of the Molex design which will work, but you may as well just get the official Molex connector if you're only buying a small quantity. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector#Motherboard_power_connector_.28Molex_Mini-fit_Jr._5566-20A_or_5566-24A.29